# Contradictory relationship between quality factor and damping

Tags: control, control-system, bandwidth, vibration, control-theory

I am studying control theory and mechanical vibrations.

From control theory aspect, I know that bandwidth and response time is inversely proportional, which means bandwidth and damping as well.

The definition of quality factor states that damping and bandwidth (specifically half maximum power bandwidth) are not inversely but directly proportional.

What am I missing? Can someone please explain?

$$Q \simeq \frac{1}{2\xi} \simeq \frac{w_n}{w_1 - w_2}$$

Comment: I have converted your equation to [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) (edit may be pending).  Please check that I have done so correctly.

Comment: HZ, where did you get the right side expression in that equation? For a 2nd order bandpass transfer function, It's not true. (What is true is that \$Q=\frac{\omega_n}{\omega_{_\text{H}}+\omega_{_\text{L}}}\$. Note the **+** instead of **-**. You can apply something called the *fractional bandwidth* to it in order to get the right side of your expression, though. But only if you apply it and then it's not the same thing, anymore. So I'm curious. Perhaps I don't understand fully your context.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming a resonant device like a tuned-circuit or a cantilever.

> *But definition of quality factor states that damping and
> bandwidth(specifically half max power bandwidth) are not inversely but
> directly proportional. What am I missing?*

They are directly proportional; if \$\zeta\$ (damping ratio) is low then, bandwidth is low.

If bandwidth is low then Q is high.

Comment: But what about controllers,if a compansator lowers bandwidth,then response become slower which means damping increases.
But because Q became higher as bandwidth decrease,means damping should decrease..
It just doesnt make sense..

Comment: I will only answer specific examples such as stated at the top of my answer. Your extra question does not seem that clearly defined and then, if you did clearly define it then, you might then ask another question on a different controller or filter so, where does this end? This site isn't geared up as a progressive teaching aid and neither is this site a forum or talking shop. You ask a question in your allotted area and I provide an answer in my allotted space.

Comment: What do you mean by not clearly defined?You replied same thing what i already stated with just an example which doesnt answer my question.Im looking for explanation to stated contradiction, intuitively or mathematically.Anyway thanks for your try.

Comment: @Tym Show your reference for the right-hand expression.

Answer (score 0):

Your take on control theory with regard to bandwidth and damping agrees with my own understanding. Take for example a negative feedback amplifier - increasing the size of the compensation capacitor to increase phase margin, increases damping, reduces both the open loop and closed loop -3dB frequency (bandwidth) resulting in better stability. Doesn't the equation in your question only apply to a band pass filter?

Comment: Yes i guess it can be seen as band pass filter.I mean bode/frequency plot for 1 DOF mass-damp-spring system.But from quality factor perspective,looks like damping and bandwith directly proportional which is not the case for bandpass filters.Confusing..

Comment: @Tym Show your reference for the right-hand expression.

Comment: My textbook is mechanical vibrations by Singiresu S. RAO but similiar equations exist on wiki page for Q factor. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor
Can it be because it is band-pass filter,and "increased bandwidth leads decrese in damping" rule applies only for lowpass filters ?

Comment: @Tym Where *exactly* in the Wiki article do you see your right-hand expression developed? I seem to be missing it.